# Written a excel macro to calculate the sum from two different range, and this will will check the 5000 rows one by one. How to reduce the runtime?

Tags: excel, vba

> Please find my code below;

```
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
```

> To repeat the task till the data range

```
Set Rng_1 = Range(Cells(i, C_Start), Cells(i, C_End))
```

> Setting the range 1

```
Set Rng_2 = Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, C_End))
```

> Setting the range 2

```
Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng_1)
```

> Addition of the range 1

```
Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng_2)
```

> Addition of the range 2

```
i = i + 1 
Loop
```

> Incrementing the value for next row

Comment: Why are you using VBA as an intermediary for the worksheet sum function? Why not just put `=SUM()` formulas in the target cells (you can place these formulas using VBA if need be). Doing so will increase speed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the range for the sum will change everytime when I run this macro. How to use '= SUM()' in a macro code?

Comment: Try array, will make it faster

Comment: The idea would be to, every time you run the macro, populate the relevant range of cells with the appropriate formulas. You should be able to do it without a loop since the `formula` property(or perhaps `R1C1Formula`) of an entire range can be set in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'formulaR1C1' we can eliminate the loop code. Please see the code below.

```
Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(RC" & C_Start & ":RC" & C_End & ")"
Range("C4").FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(RC4:RC" & C_End & ")"
Range("A4").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

Using this method the macro completes the task within a minute